# Does the product (by an object) in an abelian category ever have a right adjoint?

Tags: abelian-categories, ct.category-theory

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10290/can-a-topos-ever-be-an-abelian-category).  Since an abelian category cannot be cartesian closed, clearly the hom functor is not right adjoint to the product (by an object).  However, does the product (by an object) admit a right adjoint for some objects?  If so, what is it?  Does it exist in general?  Does it only hold for finite products?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In an additive category the functor F(–) = – × A = – ⊕ A cannot have a right adjoint unless A = 0.  If F had a right adjoint then it would preserve coproducts and in particular A = F(0) = F(0 ⊕ 0) = F(0) ⊕ F(0) = A ⊕ A via the fold map.  This means Hom(A, K) = Hom(A, K) × Hom(A, K) for every K, but Hom(A, K) is nonempty (we have zero maps) so Hom(A, K) = • and thus A = 0 by Yoneda.

Comment: And Reid Barton scores again!

Comment: There are nontrivial sets which are isomorphic to their product with themselves.  What about if A and A^2 are isomorphic, e.g. if A is an infinite direct sum of isomorphic objects?

Comment: Right, that's why I said "via the fold map".  The equality Hom(A, K) = Hom(A, K) x Hom(A, K) is being induced by the diagonal (I was a little sloppy in the notation).

Comment: Ah, right.  One way to say this is that product with A, being a left adjoint, should preserve the colimit of the empty diagram (which is the initial object of the category).

Comment: Oh, yeah, that's much simpler!

Comment: Even worse, it is exactly the same argument I made in my answer to the other question :P

Comment: Perhaps "Did you try taking the colimit of the empty diagram?" should go in the FAQ somewhere.